# use a "temporary table" and "while loop" together in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to create a table and after that use the table information in a while loop. I had been used 'with' to create the table but my code has error. The code comes below:

```
declare @i integer
set @i=0;

with cte as
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ItemID) as RowNumber,*,DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),AdDateTo)as DaysToExpire
FROM KenticoCMS1.dbo.AD_Advertise inner join KenticoCMS1.dbo.CMS_User 
    ON KenticoCMS1.dbo.AD_Advertise.ItemCreatedBy = KenticoCMS1.dbo.CMS_User.UserID
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),AdDateTo) in (SELECT RemainDays FROM KenticoCMS1.dbo.AD_SendEmailForExpire)
    AND AdShow=1)
--SELECT * FROM cte 

while (  @i<=(select max(RowNumber) from cte))
BEGIN   
        @i=@i+1;
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='ExpireAdvertiseEmail',
    @recipients= select Email FROM cte where RowNumber=@i , --'mj.yazdani1988@gmail.com',
    @subject='Test message',
    @body='This is the body of the test message.Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.'      
END
GO
```

and my error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'while'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

Comment: Hi Marjan Yazdani!! you should first search on google about temp table first

Comment: @AliSarshogh I searched..  but I didn't find anything special ... so I used "with" as usual. I didn't want to declare a table because I had so much column and I am lazy (Like u! u were wrote it in your profile). So I asked it here and I learned cursor! that I didn't used before...

Comment: thanks lady... so your site is wow...i'm proud of you ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use CTE as temporary table. You could create table (or declare table variable), put your data there and do your work:

```
create table #temp (RowNumber int, Email nvarchar(max)
```

But so far looks like your code could be changed like this:

```
declare @Email nvarchar(max)

declare cur cursor local fast_forward for
    select
        u.Email 
    from KenticoCMS1.dbo.AD_Advertise as a
        inner join KenticoCMS1.dbo.CMS_User as u on u.UserID = a.ItemCreatedBy 
    where
        a.AdShow = 1 and
        datediff(day, getdate(), a.AdDateTo) in 
        (
            select t.RemainDays
            from KenticoCMS1.dbo.AD_SendEmailForExpire as t
        )

open cur
while 1 = 1
begin
    fetch cur into @Email
    if @@fetch_status <> 0 break

    exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @profile_name = 'ExpireAdvertiseEmail',
        @recipients = @Email,
        @subject = 'Test message',
        @body = 'This is the body of the test message.Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.'      

end
close cur
deallocate cur
```

Note table aliases, removing redundant brackets. I think it'll also helps to remove datediff, but have to see your data before.

Comment: If you don't mind sending one letter to all recipients, I think it's even possible to do this without cursor, just by concatenating emails in one long string

Comment: Subject and body is different for each recipient. I declared some other variables in the top and in cursor...

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with a @TableVariable instead of a #TempTable ?

Answer (score 0):

try this: put this part

```
while (  @i<=(select max(RowNumber) from cte))
BEGIN   
        @i=@i+1;
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='ExpireAdvertiseEmail',
    @recipients=  (
```

before

```
with cte as
```

and a

```
   )
```

after

```
...where RowNumber=@i
```

for my understanding the cte definition must be followed directly by select (and it can be used in only that one select that follows)

hope it helps...

EDIT: commas obviously part of parameterlist for function